# Android Development - new activity opening too quickly

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on an app that takes a picture and then switches to a new activity. Here is the function that does so:

```
public void takePhoto(View view){
    final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    // open camera
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }

    // open "Enter Info" screen
    startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EnterInfoActivity.class));
}
```

However, the "Enter Info" activity opens before the camera. I would like the camera to open before starting the new activity. Pressing "back" brings me to the camera, which to me means that the camera does indeed load, but the activity is given a higher priority.

Comment: startActivityForResult has a callback function, So you have to put the next Intent in the block

Answer (score 1):

```
private void captureImage() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE);
}

in onActivityResult Open Your Second Activity

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // if the result is capturing Image
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_CAPTURE_IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // successfully captured the image
            // display it in image view
            previewCapturedImage();
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // user cancelled Image capture
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "User cancelled image capture", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        } else {
            // failed to capture image
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! Failed to capture image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}
```

moew info see this, http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you are using startActivityForResult to start the photo activity, which means that this new Activity you are opening will return a value calling the method `onActivityResult`.

Implement the method, and check if you come from the activity of the photo, then open the next activity.

Your flow would be something like that:

- Start photo activity
- When the photo activity ends, the method `onActivityResult` will be called
- From `onActivityResult` start the EditInfo activity

You can find specific information about managing activities from this answer: 
[How to manage `startActivityForResult` on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android#10407371)

PD: I can not test code and there has been some time since I wrote code for Android. If I get home and I can start a little android project without hassle I'll post some example.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like the camera to open before starting the new activity.

Then do not call `startActivity()` for `EnterInfoActivity` until you get called in `onActivityResult()` from the `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` activity. So, you wait for the results from `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`, *then* start the next activity.